# Combining Spatial Dataframes with different columns

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial, raster, r-sp

I have three different spatial dataframes that I'm trying to combine as one big one. The reproducible code looks like this:

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)
library(tigris)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)


# Dataset 1 ---------------------------------------------------------------

set1 <- voting_districts("nevada") 
set1 <- subset(set1,set1$COUNTYFP10 != '003')
set1 <- subset(set1,set1$COUNTYFP10 != '031')

# Dataset 2 ---------------------------------------------------------------

#Dataset Download Link:
#https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3e738fdaca2b4aeba0c18a2478cae956_0.zip?outSR=%7B%22wkid%22%3A102707%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A3421%7D

dsn <- "./Precincts"
set2 = readOGR(dsn)


# Dataset 3 ---------------------------------------------------------------

#Dataset Download Link:
#https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/fcab7fcd0b2e4243b4f6d7292c2e4daa_7.zip?outSR=%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A3423%2C%22wkid%22%3A102709%7D

dsn <- "./Voter_Districts"
set3 = readOGR(dsn)


# Transform ---------------------------------------------------------------

set1 <- spTransform(set1, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
set2 <- spTransform(set2, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
set3 <- spTransform(set3, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))


# Plot --------------------------------------------------------------------

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons( fillColor = "red",
               color = "black",
               weight = 1.0, data = set1) %>%
  addPolygons( fillColor = "blue",
               color = "black",
               weight = 1.0, data = set2) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = "green",
              color = "black",
              weight = 1.0, data = set3)
```

What I would like to do is combine them all into one big `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` that would allow me to do the same plot as above, but without the need for two additional `addPolygons` functions. Something like this:

```
leaflet(combined_sets) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(...)
```

Is that even possible? Given that they are three different datasets with different columns, I'm not sure if it can be done.

Comment: Hi, sorry but without the files it is not reproducible. But could it be that this link can help you? [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155328/merging-multiple-spatialpolygondataframes-into-1-spdf-in-r]

Comment: @JohannesStötzer I did include the files. set2 and set3 include the download link.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, there are soltions. Both `bind`and `raster::union`worked for me

```
ab <- bind(set2,set3)
ab <- raster::union(set2,set3)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons( fillColor = "blue",
               color = "black",
               weight = 1.0, data = ab)
```

[image]